# Getting unitialized constant when trying to create more than one user in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, factory-bot, testunit

I'm trying to create two users with factory girl where each has a different `sign_in_count` (using Devise). So far the first test goes great, but when it comes the second, I get an error that the second user is not initialized. The test suite is Test::Unit (not RSpec) if that matters.

Here's the test

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

   test 'user should be redirected to profile edit on first login' do
     @user = create(:user, sign_in_count: 0)
     visit(new_user_session_path)
     fill_in('user_email', :with => @user.email)
     fill_in('user_password', :with => 'foobar')
     click_button('Log in')
     assert_current_path(edit_user_registration_path)
     logout(@user)
   end

   test 'user should be taken to root on subsequent logins' do
     @other_user = create(:other_user, sign_in_count: 5)
     visit(new_user_session_path)
     fill_in('user_email', :with => @other_user.email)
     fill_in('user_password', :with => 'foobar')
     click_button('Log in')
     assert_current_path(root_path)
   end
end
```

and the factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
  sequence(:id) { |n| n }

  factory :user do
    email
    password 'foobar'
    password_confirmation 'foobar'
    id
    after(:create) { |user| user.confirm }
  end

  factory :other_user do
    email
    password 'foobar'
    password_confirmation 'foobar'
    id
    after(:create) { |user| user.confirm }
  end
end
```

and the error

```
ERROR["test_user_should_be_taken_to_root_on_subsequent_logins", ApplicationControllerTest, 0.8529229999985546]
 test_user_should_be_taken_to_root_on_subsequent_logins#ApplicationControllerTest (0.85s)
NameError:         NameError: uninitialized constant OtherUser
            test/controllers/application_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:ApplicationControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FactoryGirl tries to find model with class name `OtherUser`. But you dont have that model. Instead you want to use `User` model but you are using different factory name.

So, Adding the class name will fix the issue

```
factory :other_user, class: User do
  email
  password 'foobar'
  password_confirmation 'foobar'
  id
  after(:create) { |user| user.confirm }
end
```

Comment: This works, thank you! and thank you for the explanation

Comment: You also probably don't want to be setting the id in the factory, that will get set automatically by the database, and in this example there is no need to have the other_user factory at all -- just create a second instance of user

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone Yes, actually you don't need a new factory for that

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Ah, yes you're right, that was leftover code from when I was trying to hack a solution together. Thank you for the catch!